# Possible to "undo" sending HTTP headers and such mid-execution in a PHP script?

Tags: php, http, buffer

I'm writing a little PHP authentication library(please hold off the "don't write your own". I've done this before). As part of my library I want to be able to "abort" execution in some cases.

For instance, take this example:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
  $auth=... 
  $auth.RequiresInGroup("admin");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want `RequiresInGroup` to do is basically check if a user is logged in (by looking at the cookies and such).. and if they are not logged in or in that group, then it needs to send back a 401 error and do a server-side redirect to a not authorized page.

I know that I could move my `<?php..` statement bit above `<html>` to make this work, but I'm trying to cover all possible use cases(including poor code design).

Is there a way in PHP to basically hold off on sending content to the client until the end of the request or some similar way to send different HTTP headers in the middle of execution and then exit out of the script?

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the "control output buffering section" of the manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php

Headers themselves are not sent until your first bit of output - then the response code gets sent, followed by customer headers you have set. You can see if they have been sent using headers_sent() function. But you can't actually cancel headers once you've set them.

So buffer up what you need to send, then spit out the buffer at the end of the application.

---

Edit: another way of doing this (and the way I prefer, although it relies on a global or singleton class, that can both be frowned upon) is to create your own "output" class. Set that as a global (or singleton) and append output to that. Then you can send headers willy-nilly, and pump your output at the end of execution. Not as "unit test friendly" as ob_functions, but easier to debug and control.